# Layer lifted and separated from ESD PLA

Tags: pla, print-material

I'm using the default Ultimaker Cura draft profile but with the nozzle temp at 220 °C because this is a special ESD filament.

All was going well after some troubleshooting thanks to some users on 3DPrinting.SE but this happened over night:

What would cause an entire layer to lift off the main body, continue to print and then turn to spaghetti?

The red circled part was supposed to be part of the blue outline.
[image: failed print detail]

Comment: Please take pictures while is is still on the bed next time, it is really hard to make something of it now. Do you mean that the back part should have been on the top part?

Comment: This is what I call a wayward print! ;-)

Comment: I was running late for work and was supposed to bring this into a friend so I just removed it and took pictures. I updated the post with what was supposed to happen. 

The part that got lifted had several good layers on it.

Comment: Barring a mechanical issue where the bed dropped all of a sudden, I would suspect a clog. The filament got stuck, the printer continued printing air for a few layers and then the clog somehow resolved itself. Maybe the layer geometry changed forcing more material through which created enough pressure to break it free, maybe ramming with retractions dislodged it, who knows.

Of-course it may also be a simple mistake of attempting to print something that hangs in mid-air without supports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spool kept getting caught on itself and tightening. I unrolled some of it and rewound it and the print came out perfect. @anttix was almost correct with the clog theory.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution! Filament entanglement is always something to look out for.